# PHP foreach gets stripslashes() expects parameter 1

Tags: php, stripslashes

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(11) {
    ["deductionspayment"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["amount"]=>
        string(4) "1.03"
        ["year"]=>
        string(4) "2017"
        ["month"]=>
        string(5) "March"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["amount"]=>
        string(4) "1.03"
        ["year"]=>
        string(4) "2017"
        ["month"]=>
        string(5) "April"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(3) {
        ["amount"]=>
        string(4) "1.03"
        ["year"]=>
        string(4) "2017"
        ["month"]=>
        string(3) "May"
      }
    }
    ["deductionsname"]=>
    string(3) "SSS"
    ["deductionstart"]=>
    string(10) "2017-03-08"
    ["deductionsend"]=>
    string(10) "2017-03-14"
    ["deductionsamount"]=>
    string(4) "3.09"
    ["deductionsyears"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["deductionsdate"]=>
    string(10) "2017-03-18"
    ["deductionschedule"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["deductionstype"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["deductionsprincipalamount"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["deductionsinterest"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
}
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in 
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in 
{"error":false,"message":"Update Successful.!"}
```

This is my var_dump of my `$jsondeduction` and I am using this in foreach like

```
foreach ($jsondeduction as $val) {
                $jsondeductionspayments = json_decode(stripslashes($val['deductionspayment']), true);
```

But i am getting error and i am assuming that the error is coming from this line :
`$jsondeductionspayments = json_decode(stripslashes($val['deductionspayment']), true);`

How should I format this data to allow `stripslashes`

Comment: The first question is - why do you even use `stripslashes`?

Comment: to remove slashes in case there are slashes?

Comment: the error itself says you should pass string instead array (of arrays)

Answer (score 0):

[stripslashes](http://php.net/stripslashes) :

> stripslashes — Un-quotes a quoted ***string***

```
string stripslashes ( string $str )
```

stripslashes expects a string parameter while you are sending an array `$val['deductionspayment']` which is not a string variable

Answer (score 0):

Try This one :

```
foreach ($jsondeduction as $val) {
                $jsondeductionspayments = stripslashes(json_decode($val['deductionspayment']), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Stripslashes work on string. You provided an array $val['deductionspayment'].

```html
string stripslashes ( string $str );
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is generated due to stripslashs array.

```
$jsondeduction_decode=json_decode($jsondeduction)
$jsondeduction_stripslash=unstrip_array($jsondeduction_decode['deductionspayment']);

     function unstrip_array($array){
        foreach($array as &$val){
            if(is_array($val)){
                $val = unstrip_array($val);
            }else{
                $val = stripslashes($val);
            }
        }
    return $array;
    }
```